# Deleteing specific file type from 2 directory levels up

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to figure out a way to make a script to remove files of a specifc type from multiple folders without removing it from the 1st directory. See below for an example.

Target file extention is .xlsm

The files to be deleted are located 2 directory levels up. But I need to skip the filetype located 1 directory level up

e.g.

```
\User Folder\Folder1\test.xlsm this needs to be kept
\User Folder\Folder1\SubFolder1\File.xlsm This must be deleted 
\User Folder\Folder2\foo.xslm this needs to be kept
\User Folder\Folder2\Subfolder2\bar.xlsm This must be deleted
```

Comment: This is not a code request service, we help you to fix your problematic code. To do that you need to submit a [mcve] of your code, together with all of the information we need to replicate a reported issue when that code is run. When you [edit] your question to include that code, please delete the assigned tag for the scripting language you are not using. You should not be spamming multiple scripting language tags, use only the one which matches your submitted code, [[tag:powershell]] or [[tag:batch-file]].

Comment: Appologies this was because i wasnt even sure how to start not knowing the terminology. Now I have seen some examples I can build up a working script with additional parameters i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet can take wildcards in its search path.

Try

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\User Folder\*\*\*' -File -Filter '*.xlsm' | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` safety switch if what is shown in the console is correct and run again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do a get-childItem of Folder1 in a variable.
Then keep only folder in this variable.
And finally do your cd/set-location for delete xlsm file.

Example (I haven't try but the form is normally good) :

```
$VarFolder = Get-ChildItem ...\Folder1\
foreach ($item in $VarFolder){if ($(get-item $item).Attributes -eq "Directory"){$VarKeeping += $item }}
```

Then next of treatement with cd and remove..